# How to parse a delimited string and merge into a final array

Tags: php

I have an issue getting this functionality just right. This is for a client autocompete box. The client can have 3 different contacts with their respective phone numbers, along with their address, etc.

Once this data is retrieved from the database, I need to merge it into the client array so that it can be displayed to the user.

This is what the data coming from the database looks like right now, together with the other client data:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [ClientName] => Test 1
        [ClientAddress] => 1234 Maple St
        [Contacts] => Sue Miller:7495872472:1,Paul Miller:8975247624:2,Amy Miller:9762547627:3
        [ClientId] => 22
    )
)
```

I need to separate out the contacts, parse the string and ultimately wind up with an array that looks like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
        [ClientName] => Test 1
        [ClientAddress] => 1234 Maple St
        [name1] => Sue Miller
        [phone1] => 7495872472
        [contact1Id] => 1
        [name2] => Paul Miller
        [phone2] => 8975247624
        [contact2Id] => 2
        [name3] => Amy Miller
        [phone3] => 9762547627
        [contact3Id] => 3
        [ClientId] => 22
    )
)
```

How can I achieve this? Can someone please guide me here?

Comment: Use explode to split it on the `,` then again on the `:`, then use array_merge or a loop to bring them into one array.

Comment: Thanks Musa. I'll try that and see where I get. Thank you for the direction.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use a couple of `explode` calls to break up your contacts string into first contacts then name, phone and contactID. Then you'll put them into the array with the original data:

```
$new_array = array();

foreach($array as $key => $current) {
    $contacts = explode(",", $current['Contacts']);
    $new_array[$key] = array(
        'ClientName' => $current['ClientName'],
        'ClientAddress' => $current['ClientAddress']
    );
    $i = 1;
    foreach($contacts as $contact) {
        list($name, $phone, $clientID) = explode(":", $contact);
        $new_array[$key]['name' . $i] = $name;
        $new_array[$key]['phone' . $i] = $phone;
        $new_array[$key]['contact' . $i . 'Id'] = $clientID;
        $i++;
    }
    $new_array[$key]['ClientId'] = $current['ClientId'];
}

echo '<pre>'; print_r($new_array); exit;
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [ClientName] => Test 1
            [ClientAddress] => 1234 Maple St
            [name1] => Sue Miller
            [phone1] => 7495872472
            [contact1Id] => 1
            [name2] => Paul Miller
            [phone2] => 8975247624
            [contact2Id] => 2
            [name3] => Amy Miller
            [phone3] => 9762547627
            [contact3Id] => 3
            [ClientId] => 22
        )

)
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. I'm trying these out now. Let me ask you, why are you using one more foreach loop than Klaus, below? Just curious.

Comment: Nevermind, scrowler, I see what you're doing now. Sorry, I'm mentally exhausted right now. :)

Comment: Thank you for the answer and the effort, Scrowler.

Comment: Cool, if you're likely to have fields changing on you, best to go with one of the answers below.

Answer (score 0):

That's pretty simple parsing:

```
<?php

$data = "Sue Miller:7495872472:1,Paul Miller:8975247624:2,Amy Miller:9762547627:3";

$contacts = explode(',', $data);

foreach ($contacts as $number => $contact) {
    $info = explode(':', $contact);
    $contactInfo["name{$number}"] = $info[0];
    $contactInfo["phone{$number}"] = $info[1];
    $contactInfo["contact{$number}Id"] = $info[2];
}

print_r($contactInfo);
```

Comment: Klaus, thank you. I'm getting undefined offsets for the name and phone. I think I get the jest of what's going on here. Thank you for the help

Comment: you need to increment `$number` it will give you a result of `name0` in your contacts

Comment: @DrixsonOseña, thanks. I've got that now. I'm still struggling with this. :)  I'll be back in a few. Thank you for your answer also!

Answer (score 0):

Just to share an answer. Updating Klaus answer and adding mine , I assume you'll be processing a lot of data.

```
$myarr = array(
    array('ClientName' => 'Test 1',
        'ClientAddress' => '1234 Maple St',
        'Contacts' => 'Sue Miller:7495872472:1,Paul Miller:8975247624:2,Amy Miller:9762547627:3',
        'ClientId' => '22')
);



foreach($myarr as $index => $arr){

    foreach($arr as $key => $value){

        if($key == 'Contacts'){ //check if key is Contacts before processing
         $user_contacts = explode(',', $value);

            foreach ($user_contacts as $number => $contact) {
                $number++; //increment the index to start at 1 and not with 0

                $info = explode(':', $contact);
                $contactInfo["name{$number}"] = $info[0];
                $contactInfo["phone{$number}"] = $info[1];
                $contactInfo["contact{$number}Id"] = $info[2];
            }


            $newArr = array_merge((array)$arr, (array)$contactInfo);
        }
    }
}

print_r($newArr);
```